# List Comprehension Based On 2 Lists

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Given `A` and `B` are lists of integers, how would you add the individual elements and create a new list using their sums? What is the issue with this code and how would you do this? The errors are respectively:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack

and

> NameError: name 'b' is not defined

```
C = [a+b for (a,b) in (A,B)]

C = [a+b for a in A, b in B]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113822/list-comprehension-to-merge-various-lists-in-python

Comment: What are your inputs and outputs? Do you want the output length to be `len(A) * len(B)`, `min(len(A), len(B))`, `max(len(A), len(B))`, ...?

Comment: Just posting some code without any explanation of what you're trying to do is usually not a great idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, assuming that both lists are of equal size:

```
C = [a+b for (a,b) in zip(A,B)]
```

The trick here is using the [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) built-in function for joining both lists pair-wise.

Comment: Ah, so reading the python docs for zip() I'm understanding it returns the tuple as an iterable object similar to how list() would for a list? And it seems as map() would for functions?

Comment: `zip()` returns a list of tuples in Python 2.x or an iterator of tuples in Python 3.x. `map()` applies a function to each element in a list and (again) returns a list in Python 2.x and an iterator in Python 3.x

Answer (score 0):

You can use map, sum, and zip:

```
>>> A=[1,2,3]
>>> B=[10,20,30]
>>> map(sum, zip(A, B))
[11, 22, 33]
```

If your lists are of different lengths, you can use [izip_longest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) with a value of 0 for a fillvalue:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> A=[1,2,3]
>>> B=[10,20,30,40]
>>> map(sum, izip_longest(A, B, fillvalue=0))
[11, 22, 33, 40]
>>> map(sum, izip_longest(A, B, [100], fillvalue=0))
[111, 22, 33, 40]
```